# Third time visa refusal

Tags: visa-refusals

[image]

Well this is my third uk visa refusal and although two times before the ECO said that there was no problem with my salary, yet this time this was his reply 
Regarding the other reason, you tell me

And for those who will tell me to hire a lawyer, well i contacted alot even lawyers in UK yet they answer by that they don't deal with egyptian citizens or they don't deal with the ukvi at all

Comment: If you've been refused three times in a row, it's really time to stop and get professional help (specifically from a UK immigration lawyer, as opposed to any old lawyer) or at least reconsider and stop making further applications that can damage your credibility and make you look desperate. But for this specific situation, can you explain whether what the ECO said was accurate? Is your salary reflected in deposits in your bank statement? Are you spending more than half your savings for the trip? Also, it looks like there is more to the refusal letter; it might help if you post the whole thing.

Comment: Regarding my financial situation ... i have money ... my father died and i inherited alot of money ... i provided documents which prove this and never said that i will spend half of my savings on this trip, there is a 3rd refusal reason i forgot to mention as the ECO claims that i did not mention my previous 2 refusals and did not reply to these concerns although i mentioned in both my cover letter and the online application that i got rejected twice, i even wrote the refusal reference number

Comment: Look, the nhs is begging for doctors now, but these silly immigration rules made many people including me say why am i wasting my time with someone who doesn't need my help? I can go to any other country and earn even more money than UK, we offered help and the nhs is asking the immigration office to make the process easier but this won't happen soon

Comment: as for my cover letter, i made a friend who lives in the UK and speaks english very well write it for me

Comment: They are not refusing because of my financial situation, they are refusing because of plab, because they know that this means that one day me or anyone else will come to work in the nhs but they have a problem with the salaries

Comment: @samir287 I see no problem with a country requiring that its medical professionals can speak and write its native language to a high level. If you feel the ECO has blatantly ignored robust, genuine evidence, or has discriminated against you, try emailing the issuing UKVI hub, the Embassy in your country and the independent chief inspector of Borders and Immigration. If you just want to be able to practice medicine outside your own country, try applying elsewhere.

Comment: I have trouble finding a _question_ in this post.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ilpa.org.uk/pages/find-immigration-advice.html

Try finding a lawyer via the Immigration Law Practitioners Association.

In answer to your question, which is clearly influenced by your frustration, each application is assessed individually and your financial situation is assessed as a whole. By that I mean salary, assets and savings are considered together. On your other questions on this site it appears that the way you present information to the visa office is confusing.

This is why several people advised you to use a lawyer. You were unable to find one and decided to try again alone. As predicted here, your application failed again.

Because you have difficulty expressing yourself in English, I think there is a risk you will fail the plab once you get to the UK. You should try to find a practice plab service in Egypt or via video over the internet (sorry, I don't have any more information about this) before spending any more time and money on visas.

Comment: While I understand and share your frustration, and your advice is excellent, the final sentence seems unnecessarily hostile. Would you perhaps consider removing it?

Comment: I have adjusted it to be more constructive. However I do believe people should not be doing jobs like this in a language which they have not mastered.

Answer (score 1):

The ECO has to be able to match the employment letter and salary slip you provided with deposits in your bank account, this helps to show that the former are genuine. Planning to spend more than half your savings on the trip isn’t credible given your level of income (see ‘Proportionality’ here [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)